# Create dynamically file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to create few file ".txt" in Matlab and I want that each file has a different name, depending on a variable.

I have the variable `choose_pol` that can assume different values (1, 2, 3 and so on) and for each one I need a different file.

Right now I'm using `dlmwrite (file.txt, THETA)` to save what I have inside the matrix THETA in file.txt. Now since THETA changes depending on this variable `choose_pol` I whant to save the file depending on what I choose.

Then in an another script I need to read the txt file still depending on what I need. How can I do it?

Comment: Use `['file' num2str(choose_pol) '.txt']` instead of `'file.txt'` as file name

Comment: What if I want to use choose_pol as index in which each number is a specific name? In case I need a format like text_(name associated to choose_pol).txt

Comment: Then use something like `filenames = {'ABC', 'DEFG'}; choose_pol = 2; dlmwrite(['text_' filenames{choose_pol} '.txt'], THETA)`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to create a string from a variable:

```
filenames = {'ABC', 'DEFG'}; 
choose_pol = 2; 
dlmwrite(sprintf('%s.txt',filenames{choose_pol}), THETA)
```